# Conversion from binary to decimal number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, data-conversion

I have a problem in converting the binary to decimal (it seems very lengthy).

```
%% Read

clear all;
close all;
clc;
I=imread('test.png');
imshow(I);

%% Crop
I2 = imcrop(I);
figure, imshow(I2)
w=size(I2,1);
h=size(I2,2);
%% LBP
for i=2:w-1
    for j=2:h-1
        J0=I2(i,j);
        I3(i-1,j-1)=I2(i-1,j-1)>J0;
        I3(i-1,j)=I2(i-1,j)>J0;
        I3(i-1,j+1)=I2(i-1,j+1)>J0; 
        I3(i,j+1)=I2(i,j+1)>J0;
        I3(i+1,j+1)=I2(i+1,j+1)>J0; 
        I3(i+1,j)=I2(i+1,j)>J0; 
        I3(i+1,j-1)=I2(i+1,j-1)>J0; 
        I3(i,j-1)=I2(i,j-1)>J0;
        LBP(i,j)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^8+I3(i-1,j)*2^7+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^6+I3(i,j+1)*2^5+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j)*2^3+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^2+I3(i,j-1)*2^1;
    end
end
figure,imshow(I3)
figure,imhist(LBP)
```

Is it possible to change this line

```
LBP(i,j)=I3(i-1,j-1)*2^8+I3(i-1,j)*2^7+I3(i-1,j+1)*2^6+I3(i,j+1)*2^5+I3(i+1,j+1)*2^4+I3(i+1,j)*2^3+I3(i+1,j-1)*2^2+I3(i,j-1)*2^1;
```

to something shorter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Option 1:

One way to simplify what you're doing is to first create a 3-by-3 matrix of scale factors (i.e. powers of two) and initialize it before your loops:

```
scale = 2.^[8 7 6; 1 -inf 5; 2 3 4];
```

Then you can replace everything inside your loop with these vectorized operations:

```
temp = (I2(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1) > I2(i,j)).*scale;
LBP(i,j) = sum(temp(:));
```

### Option 2:

Alternatively, I believe you can remove both of your loops entirely and replace them with this single call to [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html) to get your matrix `LBP`:

```
LBP = nlfilter(I2,[3 3],@(x) sum((x(:) > x(5)).*scale(:)));
```

Comment: I still face a problem: my histogram is wrong. Doesnt output all the numbers

Comment: @cnn: There will be a slight difference between the results of the two options above. Option 1 will leave the edge pixels of the result as 0. Option 2 will fill them in by zero padding the original image to perform the computation. You will have to ignore the first and last rows and columns for the two results to match up. I don't know if this is the source of your histogram problem, though, since you haven't given me enough info to go on.

Comment: i have edited the code above. I am using option 1.I get 2.5 x 10^4 of 1s.something myst be wrong...but dun know what?

Comment: @cnn: I have no idea what could be wrong, especially considering you shouldn't be able to get a value of 1 for an entry in `LBP` (the lowest non-zero value should be 2).

Comment: for this statement, temp = (I2(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1)> J0).*scale, i am getting the same values as scale.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're doing there, but does [`bin2dec`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/bin2dec.html) do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding another solution with the [COLFILT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/colfilt.html) function.

It involves placing all sliding window into columns of a matrix, which we process using a custom function, then it rearranges the result into the original matrix. Internally it uses the [IM2COL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/im2col.html) and [COL2IM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/col2im.html) functions.

Here is an example:

```
I = imread('coins.png');
fun = @(b) sum( bsxfun(@times, 2.^(8:-1:1)', ...
           bsxfun(@gt, b([1 4 7 8 9 6 3 2],:), b(5,:))) );
II = colfilt(I, [3 3], 'sliding', fun);
imshow(II, [])
```

[image: screenshot]

With comparison to [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390315/conversion-from-binary-to-decimal-number-in-matlab/7390603#7390603)'s second answer, read this tip from the [NLFILTER](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/nlfilter.html) documentation:

> nlfilter can take a long time to process large images. In some cases,
>   the colfilt function can perform the same operation much faster.

Comment: firstly thanks for replying. Secondly, when i copied you function in the MATLAB,it didnt work. why is that so?

Comment: I double checked, and it works just fine.. Can you be more specific about what didn't work for you?