# Dividing LBP into 6x6 matrixes

Tags: matlab

Previously, i wrote a code for Local Binary Pattern(LBP) and Obtained a LBP image and histogram. Now i would like to divide the image into 6x6 matrixes and obtain the LBP image and histogram for each 6x6 matrix. I written the code below. But it doesnt work that well.

```
    I2=imread('CropF.jpg');
    m=size(I2,1);
    n=size(I2,2);
    counter = 1; 
    for i=2:6:m-1
        for j=2:6:n-1
            for k=i:i+6
               for l=j:j+6
                 J0=I2(k,l);
                 I3(k-1,l-1)=I2(k-1,l-1)>J0;
                 I3(k-1,l)=I2(k-1,l)>J0;
                 I3(k-1,l+1)=I2(k-1,l+1)>J0; 
                 I3(k,l+1)=I2(k,l+1)>J0;
                 I3(k+1,l+1)=I2(k+1,l+1)>J0; 
                 I3(k+1,l)=I2(k+1,l)>J0; 
                 I3(k+1,l-1)=I2(k+1,l-1)>J0; 
                 I3(k,l-1)=I2(k,l-1)>J0;
                 LBP(k,l)=I3(k-1,l-1)*2^7+I3(k-1,l)*2^6+I3(k-1,l+1)*2^5+I3(k,l+1)*2^4+I3(k+1,l+1)*2^3+I3(k+1,l)*2^2+I3(k+1,l-1)*2^1+I3(k,l-1)*2^0;
               end
            end
            LBP=uint8(LBP);
            LBPv=reshape(LBP,1,size(LBP,1)*size(LBP,2));
            Hist=hist(LBPv,0:255);
            Hist1(counter,:)= Hist;
            fname = sprintf('HistInf%03d.mat', counter);      
            save(fullfile(BASE_DIR,fname), 'Hist');     
            counter = counter + 1; 
        end
    end
    save('C:\Users\Lakshmen\Documents\MATLAB\HistInfMain','Hist1');
```

I have an error like this : `??? Index exceeds matrix dimensions`.

Morever, the value for m and n I get is 394 and 330. Hence the value i should get for counter is 55 which is what i get but I get the error said above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are still working on the problem from your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390315/conversion-from-binary-to-decimal-number-in-matlab) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457366/saving-to-a-new-file-each-time).

I am assuming that `m` and `n` denote the size of the `I2` matrix. If that is the case, then the issue here is with the two inner loops for the `k` and `l` variables. They go from the current values of `i` and `j` and go up to `i+6` and `j+6`. But `i` and `j` themselves can reach `m-1` and `n-1` respectively thus you get "out of bound" errors.

If I am correct, you need to change the upper bounds of the `i`,`j` for-loops:

```
counter = 1;
Hist1 = [];               %# you can probably pre-allocate a fixed size here
for i=2:6:m-1-6
    for j=2:6:n-1-6
        for k=i:i+6
            for l=j:j+6
                %#...
            end
        end
        %# ...
    end
end
%# ...
```

Comment: did this solve the problem (changing the for-loops upper bound)?

Comment: as I explained above, the variable `k` can go up to `i+6` thus if `i=m-1` you would get `k=m+5` which is outside the bounds of the matrix `I2` (same goes for `j` and `l` for the other dimension)

Comment: hi, thanks for explaining..understand better but is there a better way to solve this issue.. I would like to divide the image into 6 by 6 matrixes...

Comment: @cnnlakshmen: in your previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7390315/conversion-from-binary-to-decimal-number-in-matlab), there were a few functions suggested that can do that for you: COLFILT, NLFILTER, BLOCKPROC (depending on whether you want distinct or sliding blocks). Please spend time reading their respective documentation pages...